# How to iterate over nested objects in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am storing some order details in the firebase database and when I retrieve the data from it, it shows something like below.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "cartItems": Array [
      Object {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "1",
        "name": "EARRINGS",
        "pic": 20,
        "price": "200",
      },
      Object {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "2",
        "name": "Ring",
        "pic": 20,
        "price": "300",
      },
    ],
    "orderId": "OD4242JUL28",
  },
  Object {
    "cartItems": Array [
      Object {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "3",
        "name": "Staple",
        "pic": 20,
        "price": "400",
      },
      Object {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "2",
        "name": "Ring",
        "pic": 20,
        "price": "300",
      },
    ],
    "orderId": "OD4242JUL28",
  },
]
```

I m able to get the first or second object by using index in [] but after that, if I use map function on it, I am unable to iterate over it. I want to retrieve every cartItem and iterate over it to show it in the orders section.

***FLATLIST***

```
<FlatList 
          data={this.state.order}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key }
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({item}) =>(
            <View>
                <Image source={item.pic} style={{width:width/2.05,height:150}} />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.cartItems.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.orderId}</Text>
          </View>
          ) }
        />
```

This only returns orderID but `item.cartItems.name` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**@Lovepreet** Singh try to use recursion method to iterate nested array Of objects.

Comment: this link is helps you https://www.bitovi.com/blog/recursive-react-components

Comment: use scroll view instead of flat list. Inside the scroll view  we render custom structure.Use couple of map function to iterate your array of array.

Comment: If I use scrollview then how the first iteration will work. I mean to in my code item is provided by flatlist after rendering data and then I used the map on that item. But how the scrollView will do this. unable to understand

Comment: <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} >
  <View>
    {
      order.map(function(obj, i){
        return(
          <View>
            {
              obj.map(function(val, index){

              })
            }
          </View>
        )
      })
    }
  </View>
</ScrollView>

Comment: have you checked ?

Comment: This throws an error that this.state.order.map is not a function

Comment: please bind the map

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I figured out with the below code

```
<FlatList 
          data={this.state.order}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key }
          // numColumns={2}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({item}) =>(
            <View>
                <Image source={item.pic} style={{width:width/2.05,height:150}} />
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.cartItems.keys}</Text>
                {item.cartItems.map(val=>{
                  return(
                  <View>
                    <Text> {val.count} </Text>
                    <Text> {val.price} </Text>
                    <Text> {val.name} </Text>
                    <Text> {val.pic} </Text>
                    </View> )
                })}
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.orderId}</Text>
          </View>
          ) }
        />
```

It uses map function inside the flatlist and I believe there is some wrong with this as it gives a warning  `Functions are not valid as a React child.`
Please guide me the best way to do this.